# com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin helloflashlight eclipse issue

Tags: java, android, maven, eclipse-luna, android-maven-plugin

my issue is to make eclipse build the helloflashlight exemple from the android-maven-plugin

my env :

- eclipse luna x64 (on windows 7 x64 pro) set-up with:

  - jdk 1.8.0_25 (x64)
  - m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (1.6.0.20150109-0342)
  - Android for Maven Eclipse  (1.2.2.201501131540)
  - the android sdk setup
- the latest Maven installed:
- imported all android jar to my local repo using the simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer
- simpligility/android-maven-plugin checkouted on my hard drive (to get the test example)
  https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin

The issue occured just after importing a new maven project (helloflashlight: android-maven-plugin/src/test/projects/helloflashlight/) to my workspace :

i can run : mvn clean install android:deploy and it work just fine; i have the project deployed on my mobile.

but what i can't do is debugging with eclipse to put some wait point in my code.

by the way the imported project is not recognized as an android project cause the "manifest" is under "src/main/" and not at the project root folder
the "res" folder is also under "src/main".

do you know a way to debug this project ?

thank's